# Center text and shrink element to fit for elements displayed inline-block

Tags: html, css

I am currently creating a navigation bar for my site, and I've looked everywhere and tried some stuff but I couldn't figure out what I've fudged up :P

Anyways, I've got some boxes I named 'nav-box' and they hold the navigation elements inside them. I have these displayed inline-block so that they look like nav elements.

2 things now, the text inside these boxes are stuck to the left of the box, I have to have them centered. Alongside this, the boxes seem really big. Do i have to set their width manually or can I have css make them fit?

Here is the JSFiddle i have created with my code. I've tried adding 'inline-block' to both the element and it's parent container, but neither of them work for this situation :(

This is what I've tried:

```
.nav > .nav-content > .nav-inner {
    width: auto;
    float: right;
    text-align: center;
}
```

As you can see that is my parent element holding the `nav-box` element and I added the `text-align: center;`, but it still didn't do what I need.

http://jsfiddle.net/qhPwt/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The text inside the boxes are not aligned to center because there is a `margin-right` being applied to the content inside the boxes.

Check this **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/39james/7NBst/)**

CSS changes

```
.nav > .nav-content > .nav-inner > .nav-box > .nav-link:last-child {
    margin-right: 80px; // Remove this style
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I found that answer but It wouldnt let me post my own because I dont have +10 rep lol :P